# Mozilla Firefox force CSS positions value to inset format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

This is only happening on Firefox browser.
I have these absolute positioned elements with an inline style. now, I need to modify their position by setting it's top, right, bottom, left CSS values through Jquery or Vanilla JS. Everything works fine except on Firefox. when I set the element's position, Firefox sets it CSS property to ***inset***.

Sample HTML of the element with inline css. (you can see the whole code in the DEMO)

```
<div class="box" style="top: 30px; right: 30px; bottom: 30px; left: 30px"></div>
```

Please try the DEMO on a Firefox browser. clicking the ***edit css*** button will return the element's inline style.

here's the  [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/elelowwaydi_/kufgzmwc/5/)

inset CSS property [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset).

Chrome browser [**example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGsBg.jpg).

Firefox browser **[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfJLq.jpg)**.

my Firefox browser version - 67.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: The `inset` properties unfortunately applies to all positioned elements in Firefox Desktop / Firefox for Android. It's very similar to the top, left, right and bottom properties except the values move an element opposite to the direction positioned elements would move (with `top`, `left` etc.) and it can be used with a shorthand syntax. Being that Mozilla has implemented this CSS Module into their browser there doesn't seem a way around it.